# stop\start connector within my code

Tags: tomcat, connector

I need to stop and then start the https connector programmatically.
In tomcat 6 the following scrap of code works fine:

```
        final ObjectName objectNameQuery = new ObjectName("*:type=Connector,port=443,*"); 
        MBeanServer      mbeanServer = null;
        ObjectName       objectName  = null;

        for (final MBeanServer server : (List<MBeanServer>) MBeanServerFactory.findMBeanServer(null))
        {
            if (server.queryNames(objectNameQuery, null).size() > 0)
            {
                mbeanServer     = server;
                objectName      = (ObjectName) server.queryNames(objectNameQuery, null).toArray()[0];

                break;
            }
        }

        // now we restart the connector that we just found. We sleep a little, but I am
        // not actually sure 1) how long we should sleep for or 2) if sleeping is
        // necessary at all.
        if (mbeanServer != null)
        {
            mbeanServer.invoke(objectName, "stop", null, null);                

            Thread.sleep(waitForStopInSec * 1000);

            mbeanServer.invoke(objectName, "start", null, null);

            log.warn("https Connector was restarted");
        }
```

But in tomcat 7 (7.0.23) the connector does not stopped! So I invoked the destroy() method (right after invoking the stop() method) using this line of code:
mbeanServer.invoke(objectName, "destroy", null, null);

In this case the connector indeed stopped. But when I tried to start it, the connector did not start and I got this exception:

```
28/03/12 18:32:01 ERROR T:CommServerScheduler_Worker-1 TrustStoreRefreshJob.refreshHTTPSConnectors - failed to restart connector 
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException:    Catalina:type=Connector,port=443,address="/192.168.201.24"
     at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1094)
     at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:833)
     at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
     at tool.security.TrustStoreRefreshJob.refreshHTTPSConnectors(TrustStoreRefreshJob.java:79)
     at tool.security.TrustStoreRefreshJob.executeJob(TrustStoreRefreshJob.java:32)
     at com.nextnine.common.scheduler.AbstractJobLogic.execute(AbstractJobLogic.java:47)
     at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
     at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
```

Any ideas of how I can stop and then start the connector in tomcat 7? Preferable in a graceful manner.
Thanks in advance,
Guy

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you are defining "stop". By default, Tomcat binds to the port during init() and unbinds during destroy(). In the default case stop() just stops processing new connections but it may not stop those connections being made (depending on - amongst other things - the underlying OS).

You may get better results if you set bindOnInit="false" for the connector in your server.xml. With this setting the port will be bound when start() is called an unbound when stop() is called.

Comment: Mark,thanks for the response. How should I start() and stop() the Connector? Is it using the operation on the Connector MBeans like I did in my post? or there is a better way?

Comment: They way you are doing it will work. The better way - if possible - is to get hold of a reference to the actual connector object rather than going via JMX. How easy this is will depend on exactly how you are starting the Tomcat instance.

Comment: sounds good, although I'm not sure I understand what do you mean by saying "...how you are starting the Tomcat instance"... 
How can I obtain the Connector? Maybe thru a listener (ServletContextListener)?

Comment: It isn't clear if you have written a web application (in which case JMX is as good as any approach) or if you are embedding Tomcat in which case I'd expect you to have direct access to the Connector object.

Comment: Mark thanks again. Maybe I had to explain my motivation: I'm using https connector with mutual authentication. The issue is that the certificate(s) might be changed so I have to use a new SSLSocket. In tomcat6 I used the code above (stop() and right after that start()) and it worked perfectly. In tomcat7 it doesn't work! I noticed (netstat -a) that after stop() tomcat still utilizes port 443. I would expect 443 to be free after stop(). I tried destroy() but then the connector failed to start again. Any idea?

Comment: You need to set bindOnInit="false" if you want to use stop() & start().

Comment: Once you call destroy(), the component can't be restarted.

Comment: Wow, who knew someone else would have the same very niche problem as me, thanks guys!