# Can we avoid spring boot application restart, to refresh the certificates associated with its embedded tomcat container?

Tags: java, spring, security, ssl, spring-boot

With any change to the SSL certificates (in its keystore), we need to restart the spring boot application. I want to update my key store entry periodically (may be every year), but want to avoid restarting the JVM. What would it take to achieve it. I wonder if writing custom KeyManager is an acceptable practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.

#### BUT

You have several solutions here.

## Reload Tomcat connector (a bit hacky)

You can restart `Tomcat` connector i.e. restart `8843` is possible after you change your `jssecacert` file.

But I think that it is still a hack.

## Reverse proxy: `Nginx`, `Apache`

This is a way to go. Your application should be behind some reverse proxy (e.g. `nginx`). This will give you an additional flexibility and reduce load on your app. `Nginx` will handle `https` and translate it to plain `http`. Anyway, you'll have to restart `nginx`, but `nginx` restart is so fast that it will be no downtime. Moreover, you could configure script to do this for you.

Comment: I was curious to know if Spring boot has covered this. Thanks a ton. I somehow felt that if we write a custom KeyManager and hold a handle to it in my application code, I would be able to refresh it. I'm unable to validate this as spring boot doesn't offer any direct way to set the custom KeyManager. Looks like I need to write my own "Cryptographic Service Provider" to install it. My requirement is not to cause any impact on the exiting connections, but new connection originating from the client should see the new certificate (after I refresh).

Comment: Using approach #2 — you won't affect your clients. This will be transparent for them.

Comment: Found approach#1 detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912585/stop-start-connector-within-my-code  . However, I approached it without MBeans interface. i.e. introduced EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer and got hold of the connector instance and then performed "stop" and "start". However, But for long run, need to bring in approach#2.

Comment: Also, approach with reverse proxy is a way more flexible. By the way, you will be able (if you'll need it, of course) to use it as load balancer for several instances, if you'll want to scale in future.

Comment: @maheshkamath can you add an answer with your  EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer implementation?

Comment: Return a **EmbeddedServletContainerFactory** bean from spring config, container will pick it, instead of default one. Then include a customizer to get hold of connector reference (i..e httpsConnector)
webContainerFactory.addConnectorCustomizers((TomcatConnectorCustomizer) (Connector connector) -> {
httpsConnector = connector;
httpsConnector.setAttribute("bindOnInit", false); // Needed with newer versions of tomcat
});

Now that we have a handle to the connector instance, we just need to do 
httpsConnector.stop();
// Connector setting can be changed here .
httpsConnector.start();

Comment: @Yuri Kuschc - using Nginx do we need to secure the connection between the Nginx and Spring Boot? I think I get it. I setup Ngnix (web server) with SSL, then I forward the packets to the locally running spring boot on plain HTTP: http://localhost:8080 . Am I correct? If yes, then I can remove all the SSL requirements from the spring boot app.

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian yes, nginx will handle `https` part for you. Usually it is more effective than doing it with the app itself.

Answer (score 3):

On Tomcat one can use local JMX to reload SSL context:

```
private static final String JMX_THREAD_POOL_NAME = "*:type=ThreadPool,name=*";
private static final String JMX_OPERATION_RELOAD_SSL_HOST_CONFIGS_NAME = "reloadSslHostConfigs"; 
private void reloadSSLConfigsOnConnectors() {
    try {
        MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName(JMX_THREAD_POOL_NAME);
        Set<ObjectInstance> allTP = server.queryMBeans(objectName, null);
        logger.info("MBeans found: {}", allTP.size());
        allTP.forEach(tp -> reloadSSLConfigOnThreadPoolJMX(server, tp));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("", ex);
    }
}

private void reloadSSLConfigOnThreadPoolJMX(MBeanServer server, ObjectInstance tp) {
    try {
        logger.info("Invoking operation SSL reload on {}", tp.getObjectName());
        server.invoke(tp.getObjectName(), JMX_OPERATION_RELOAD_SSL_HOST_CONFIGS_NAME, new Object[]{}, new String[]{});
        logger.trace("Successfully invoked");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Invoking SSL reload", ex);
    }
}
```

I'm reloading all ThreadPool SSL context, but you really only need one: `Tomcat:type=ThreadPool,name=https-jsse-nio-8443`. I'm just afraid the name will change, so I cover all possibilities just in case.

Comment: Don't like hacks. This seems like a clean solution. Did it work, though?

Comment: @rks, sure, it worked splendidly. Shipped it to the final customer in September, it has been in constant testing for 5 months (this being quite an early feature of the app), never had a problem in that region.

Comment: I tried this verbatim with Spring Boot 2.6.5 but the message returned was "MBeans found: 0".  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Try with an object name `"*:type=*,name=*"`, see what gives. Alternatively, run your stuff locally and access it with `jconsole`, see what JMX beans are there at all.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem in my Spring Boot application by getting a
`TomcatServletWebServerFactory`
in a bean and add my own connector customizer to it.

```
@Bean
public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {

    TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    // --- CUSTOMIZE SSL PORT IN ORDER TO BE ABLE TO RELOAD THE SSL HOST CONFIG
    tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers(new DefaultSSLConnectorCustomizer());            
    return tomcat;
}
```

My customizer extracts the protocol for https for later use

```
public class DefaultSSLConnectorCustomizer implements TomcatConnectorCustomizer {

private Http11NioProtocol protocol;

@Override
public void customize(Connector connector) {

    Http11NioProtocol protocol = (Http11NioProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();
    if ( connector.getSecure()) {
        //--- REMEMBER PROTOCOL WHICH WE NEED LATER IN ORDER TO RELOAD SSL CONFIG
        this.protocol = protocol;
    }
}

protected Http11NioProtocol getProtocol() {
    return protocol;
}
```

}

When I have updated the keystore with the new private key I conduct a SSL host config reload. This code goes here

```
@Component
public class TomcatUtil {

    public static final String DEFAULT_SSL_HOSTNAME_CONFIG_NAME = "_default_";

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    private ServletWebServerFactory servletWebServerFactory;

    public TomcatUtil(ServletWebServerFactory servletWebServerFactory) {

        this.servletWebServerFactory = servletWebServerFactory;
    }

    public void reloadSSLHostConfig() {

        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatFactoty = (TomcatServletWebServerFactory) servletWebServerFactory;
        Collection<TomcatConnectorCustomizer> customizers = tomcatFactoty.getTomcatConnectorCustomizers();
        for (TomcatConnectorCustomizer tomcatConnectorCustomizer : customizers) {

            if (tomcatConnectorCustomizer instanceof DefaultSSLConnectorCustomizer) {
                DefaultSSLConnectorCustomizer customizer = (DefaultSSLConnectorCustomizer) tomcatConnectorCustomizer;
                Http11NioProtocol protocol = customizer.getProtocol();
                try {
                    protocol.reloadSslHostConfig(DEFAULT_SSL_HOSTNAME_CONFIG_NAME);
                    logger.info("Reloaded SSL host configuration");
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    logger.warn("Cannot reload SSL host configuration", e);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And finally

```
...
                renewServerCertificate();
                tomcatUtil.reloadSSLHostConfig();
```

Comment: And what does `renewServerCertificate()` do? where is it coming from?

Comment: @ jbx 
`renewServerCertificate()` gets a new server certificate and stores it into the application's keystore. Once this is done the SSL host configuration needs to reloaded by `tomcatUtil.reloadSSLHostConfig()`

Comment: Also, do I need to provide my own value for DEFAULT_SSL_HOSTNAME_CONFIG_NAME?  If so what should be used?

Comment: @opeongo use    `_default_`

Comment: I can confirm that this method works well.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Spring Boot 3.2 it's possible to hot-reload (at least for Tomcat and Netty embedded web servers).

To use the feature do the following:

1. Define an ssl bundle (let's call it "demo")

```yaml
spring.ssl.bundle.pem:
  demo:
    reload-on-update: true
    keystore:    
      certificate: "certs/demo.crt"
      private-key: "certs/demo.key"
```

2. Then point the web server to it

```yaml
server.ssl.bundle: "demo"
```

P.S. here's a good article on how to use the feature - https://spring.io/blog/2023/11/07/ssl-hot-reload-in-spring-boot-3-2-0