# Spring Boot | Use dynamic keystore/truststore

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, ssl

I need to use dynamic keystores in my Spring Boot application because at any moment i might have to change them and i don't want to have any downtime.

From what i saw it [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527478/can-we-avoid-spring-boot-application-restart-to-refresh-the-certificates-associ) post i have three options:

- Writing a custom KeyManager;
- Use a reverse-proxy;
- Or on Tomcat use local JMX to reload SSL context.

In last one i don't really understand the implications of that. The reverse-proxy seems the easier way, but is it the best approach?

If someone could point me which one would be the best solution and why or recommend something else would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your own implementation of [`SslStoreProvider`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/server/SslStoreProvider.html) which will enable you to get the keystore/truststore from whatever source you want (does not need to be on disk).
Then check out [`@RefreshScope`](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_refresh_scope) you can recreate beans (like your own `SslStoreProvider`) with it.

[Here](https://github.com/jonatan-ivanov/ssl-store-provider-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/sslstoreproviderdemo/InMemorySslStoreProvider.java) you can find an example (please note that this was only created to demonstrate a bug in spring-boot 1.x which was fixed in 2.x).

Comment: It looks like it can solve my problem! I'm pretty new with Spring Boot, so it will take a while to implement it, anyways i will give some feedback asap. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The external reverse-proxy approach is the most flexible. It doesn't require any changes to your application or deployment logic and will address most of the scenarios. The downside is that your architecture gets more complex and requires additional server resource for the proxy server.

You can take it a step further and do [blue-green deployments](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html):

> The blue-green deployment approach does this by ensuring you have two production environments, as identical as possible. At any time one of them, let's say blue for the example, is live. As you prepare a new release of your software you do your final stage of testing in the green environment. Once the software is working in the green environment, you switch the router so that all incoming requests go to the green environment - the blue one is now idle.